# Rename a column name that has space in between

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

Accidently, I rennamed my column by below:

```
AM using MSSMS 17.5v 
----------------------------

GO  
EXEC sp_rename "CloudSubscriber.Unsubscribe Reports", 'Unsubscribe', 'COLUMN'
GO 
----------------------------
```

How can I change it back to the original name?
Am not able to revert above change I made using:

```
GO  
EXEC sp_rename "CloudSubscriber.Unsubscribe", 'Unsubscribe Reports', 'COLUMN'
GO 
------------------------
```

Maybe the error is caused because of the space?

Comment: Your original code works fine http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b2d1f/1/0

Comment: no, i had to use double quotes when renaming a name with space to a name with no space. with single quotes it did not work. Below Bohemian solution clarified that.

Comment: My link is to an instance of SQL Server where it is working fine! What error were you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double quotes around the column name:

```
EXEC sp_rename "CloudSubscriber.Unsubscribe", "Unsubscribe Reports", 'COLUMN'
```

With most DBs, double quotes are for database object names, single quotes are for a text literal.

Comment: Hey Awesome! that was it. Thanks much!.

Comment: @Afar, mark this as the answer since it answered your question.

Comment: @EricBrandt the answer isn't correct. sp_rename Is a stored procedure accepting various types of nvarchar parameter. Inside the stored procedure it makes no difference if the parameter string values  outside the procedure were quoted with single or double quotes. It isn't even possible for it to detect that. Presumably the OP was making some other sort of error that they happened to avoid when trying the code in this answer.

Comment: @Afar click the tick mark to the left of the answer. It should turn from grey to green.